# Как вывести связанные между собой записи из двух таблиц сразу (база данных)?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы и пример их заполнения:

Таблица Основная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Вспомогательная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести на экран данные из этих двух таблиц таким образом, чтобы из Основной таблицы в тех записях, где значение столбца condition равно 1 выводилась эта запись + связанные с ней записи из Вспомогательной таблицы (связь происходит по столбцам id и id_item).

Пример вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как реализовать такой комплексный запрос в базу данных? Чтобы на выходе получился готовый ассоциативный массив, который можно было бы вывести на экран и легко с ним работать (фильтровать, сортировать и тд)?

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
_sum  INTEGER,
_condition TEXT
);

INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (22 , "Часы" , 12000 , NULL) ,
(43 , "Клавиатура" , 4900  ,NULL),
(78 , "Телефон" , 30000 ,1) ,
(9 , "Монитор" , 19000 ,1 ),
(12 , "Картина" , 8000  ,NULL);

SELECT * FROM table_1;

CREATE TABLE table_2(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_item INTEGER,
name TEXT ,
price INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (1 , 78 , "Samsung" , 12000 ),
(2 , 78 , "Nokia" , 10000) ,
(3 , 78 , "Panasonic" , 8000) ,
(4 ,9 , "LG" , 7000) ,
(5, 9 , "Acer" , 1200 );

SELECT * FROM table_2;

Output:

+----+----------------------+-------+------------+
| id | name                 | _sum  | _condition |
+----+----------------------+-------+------------+
|  9 | Монитор              | 19000 | 1          |
| 12 | Картина              |  8000 | NULL       |
| 22 | Часы                 | 12000 | NULL       |
| 43 | Клавиатура           |  4900 | NULL       |
| 78 | Телефон              | 30000 | 1          |
+----+----------------------+-------+------------+
+----+---------+-----------+-------+
| id | id_item | name      | price |
+----+---------+-----------+-------+
|  1 |      78 | Samsung   | 12000 |
|  2 |      78 | Nokia     | 10000 |
|  3 |      78 | Panasonic |  8000 |
|  4 |       9 | LG        |  7000 |
|  5 |       9 | Acer      |  1200 |
+----+---------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120) + [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)

Comment: Запросом такое вряд ли сделать получится. Из БД можно получить строку вида `Телефон Samsung 3000` и потом уже группировать в пхп. при этом колонки sum в таблице категорий быть не должно. Сумма должна считаться на лету. Сортировка и фильтрация тоже должны делаться в запросе.

Comment: @Ипатьев Да вроде элементарный запрос-то, UNION + CASE в ORDER BY.

Comment: @Akina а можете полный пример такого запроса написать?

Comment: Автор должен больше всех работать над решением задачи. Оформите нормально вопрос - тогда и будет предмет для разговора.

Comment: Вопрос нормально оформлен, в нём всё понятно и картинки никоим образом не мешают дать на него ответ. Так что мне на ваши фантазии о правильности задавания вопроса до одного места. Не хотите помогать - не надо, никто не расстроиться. А высокомерие в другом месте показывай своё.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_1.name AS main_name, table_1._sum,
       table_1._condition, table_2.name AS secondary_name, table_2.price
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id_item
WHERE table_1._condition = 1;
```

Результат:

```
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+ 
|id |main_name  |_sum   |_condition |secondary_name|price   |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|78 |Картина2   |30000  |1          |Samsung       |12000   |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|78 |Картина2   |30000  |1          |Nokia         |10000   |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|78 |Картина2   |30000  |1          |Panasonic     |8000    |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|9  |Клавиатура |19000  |1          |LG            |7000    |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|9  |Клавиатура |19000  |1          |Acer          |1200    |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Теперь надо обработать этот массив, и вывести в том виде, в котором заказывал клиент.